# Implement ECDiffieHellmanCng in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, xamarin, mono

I am trying to use the [Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx) for key exchange in a xamarin application. However, I am getting a reference/compilation errors for the class. My assumption is that the class is not part of Mono. Do you know of a workaround for using that algorithm in Xamarin Apps? Please share your thoughts.

Thank you!

> ECDiffieHellmanCng

```
var sessionClient = new ECDiffieHellmanCng {
                KeySize = 521,
                KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash,
                HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you can use third party solutions like,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Curve25519/

This blog post contains tons of samples for different platforms,

http://blog.srinivasan.biz/software/elliptic-curve-cryptography-computing-shared-key